# Ограничения прямоугольной области на карте при обратном геокодирование

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, карты, яндекс-карты

При поиске топонима улица с использовании обратного геокодирования задаю прямоугольную область на карте параметром options.boundedBy. Проблема в том, что при увеличении области поиска данные перестают поступать. В документации ни слова про это ограничение. Кто знает какой максимальный размер для boundedBy?

Пример на скрине (области считаем от меньшей к большей)

- rectangle 1 -> Солнечная улица
- rectangle 1 -> Солнечная улица
- rectangle 3 -> уже пусто
- rectangle 4 -> тем более пусто
- rectangle 5 -> конечно же пусто

[image: Области поиска топонима]

Пример кода, как на картинке

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  //
  const A = [34.101248, 53.163818];
  const arrayBoundedBy = [
    [
      [34.098248, 53.16081789],
      [34.104248, 53.16681789],
    ],
    [
      [34.097748, 53.16031786],
      [34.104748, 53.16731786],
    ],
    [
      [34.097248, 53.15981781],
      [34.105248, 53.16781781],
    ],
    [
      [34.096748, 53.15931776],
      [34.105748, 53.16831776],
    ],
    [
      [34.096248, 53.15881771],
      [34.106248, 53.16881771],
    ],
  ];
  //
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map(
    "map", {
      center: A,
      zoom: 15
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: "yandex#search"
    }
  );
  //
  const myPointA = new ymaps.Placemark(A, {
    iconContent: "A"
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPointA);
  //
  arrayBoundedBy.map((item, index) => {
    const myRectangle = new ymaps.Rectangle(item, {}, {
      fill: false
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myRectangle);
  });
  //
  const last = arrayBoundedBy.slice(-1);
  const myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline(last[0]);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);
  //
  const promises = arrayBoundedBy.map((item, index) => {
    const myGeocode = ymaps.geocode(A, {
      boundedBy: item,
      json: false,
      kind: "street",
    });
    return myGeocode.then((res) => {
      myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
      const found = res.geoObjects.get(0) ?
        res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get("name") :
        "пусто";
      return "rectangle " + (index + 1) + " -> " + found;
    });
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => console.log(results));
}
```

Comment: есть асболютно точный и однозначный ответ на ваш вопрос: «разработчики из yandex-а». но мне почему-то кажется, что вас такой не устроит. значит, переформулируйте вопрос, пожалуйста, нажав [edit].

Comment: А конкретный пример кода есть? Может у вас другие параметры как-то влияют на результат - ну там kind, например?

Comment: Добавил код для скрина

Comment: Действительно, странное поведение. Лучше бы прямиком в Яндекс написать - вдруг Баг. Однако без kind в массиве ответа улица всё же приходит, пусть и не первым элементом. Можно пока забирать тот из ответов, где "kind": "street".

Comment: Да, написал в ТП. Если еще смотреть в сторону документации API Геокодера, то там написано "Если параметр kind не задан, API выберет тип топонима автоматически.", так и происходит. Яндекс отдает данные: дом, улица, населенный пункт, район, область, округ.

Comment: При увеличении области, любой kind - пустота

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ разработчиков (может, кому-то пригодится):**

Без kind геокодер просто возвращает ближайшие к точке топонимы всех возможных типов, потому крупный bbox не мешает алгоритму.

Если же необходимо получить выборку объектов определённого типа (kind указан) в очерченной зоне, сервис ограничивает размер зоны (диагональ bbox) их поиска: для домов (house) и улиц (street) ограничение — 1 км, для населённых пунктов (locality) — 100 км, для станций метро — 200 км, для остальных kind ограничений нет. Больше этих значений выборка невозможна, потому ответ пустой.

Мы постараемся внести эту информацию в справку в ближайшем будущем, но конкретных сроков я вам пока назвать не смогу.